# Can I pass a more than one value in a one option from x-select addon on ember?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I would like to pass a more than one value in a one option from a x-select addon in ember. Is that possible? For example,

```
  {{#each model as |model|}}
     {{#xs.option value1=model.name value2=model.anotherAttributeName}
       {{model.name}} 
     {{/xs.option}}
  {{/each}}
```

Any suggestions and answers are much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: what does it mean for an `option` to have multiple values? what are you trying to achieve; please provide some context. an `option` should have a single `value` that determines whether the option is `selected` or not within the surrounding `select`. So what you are asking is not that clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that is not possible. option-component wraps a native `<option>` tag. option component has following attributeBindings:

```
'selected', 'name', 'disabled', 'value', 'title'
```

Just pass the whole model to option component as value.

```
{{#x-select value=selected onChange=(action "selectOption") as |xs|}}
  {{#each model as |model|}}
     {{#xs.option value=model}}
       {{model.name}} 
     {{/xs.option}}
  {{/each}}
{{/x-select}}
```

At your action you can access your whole model.

```
  actions: {
    selectOption(value) { // value is a reference to the selected model
      console.log(value.name, value.anotherProperty);
      this.set('selected', value);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you @wuarmin for the help! Appreciate it!